# C program on singly linked list returing error

Tags: c, sorting, malloc

I am trying to find out the problem with the code below. Here I have tried to create a linked list of strings which sorts the strings alphabetically, but while compiling it [on Ubuntu] it is showing an error.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<string.h>

 struct node_type {
   char data[21];
  struct node_type *next;
   };
  typedef struct node_type list;

   void showList ();
   list *sortInsert();
    list *createNode();
   list *find();
       main()
     {
    list *newnode, *start = NULL;
     char c = 'y';
     char word[21];

        while(c != 'n' && c!= 'N')
        {
      printf("\n Enter the word:");
      scanf("%s", word); fflush(stdin);
   newnode = createNode();
   strcpy(newnode->data, word);
    newnode->next = NULL;
      if(!find(start,newnode->data))
       start = sortInsert(start,newnode);
        printf("\nThe list so far:"); 
      showList(start); 
         printf("\n\n");
         printf("\n Do you want to add new data to the list? (y/n): ");
        scanf("%c", &c); getchar(); fflush(stdin);
          }
          printf("\nThe sorted list is:"); showList(start); printf("\n\n");
            }

        list *createNode()
             {
           list *new;
       new = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
         return(new);
                 }

             list *sortInsert(list *start, list *newnode)
        {
           list *prev, *curr;
          if(start==NULL)
             {
   return(newnode);
      }

       curr = start;
         prev=curr;

          if(strcmp(newnode->data, curr->data)<0)
          {
          start=newnode;
         newnode->next = curr;
       return(start);
      }

            while(curr!=NULL)
      {
          curr = curr->next;
               if(curr==NULL)
          {
          prev->next = newnode;
         newnode->next = curr;
           return(start);
          }
        else
          {
         if(strcmp(newnode->data, curr->data)<0)
          {
           prev->next = newnode;
            newnode->next = curr;
         return(start);
       }
          prev = prev->next;
        }
        }
       return(start);
          }
        list *find(list *st, int dt)
         {
         while(st)
            if(strcmp(st->data,dt) == 0)
            return (st);
       else
                st = st->next;
            return(st);
        }


          void showList(list *temp)
         {
          while(temp)
          {
            printf("%s", temp->data);
           temp = temp->next;
          }
                 printf("\n");
           }
```

The error on Linux terminal is

```
       part4.c: In function ‘find’:
       part4.c:89:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
       if(strcmp(st->data,dt) == NULL)
       ^
       In file included from part4.c:3:0:
        /usr/include/string.h:144:12: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of          type ‘int’
       extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
                       ^
     part4.c:89:26: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
     if(strcmp(st->data,dt) == NULL)
```

Kindly let me know what could be the solution.

Comment: please indent the code.

Comment: `list *find(list *st, int dt)` --> `list *find(list *st, const char *dt)`

Comment: Change arguments list of function list *find(list *st, int dt) to list *find(list *st, const char *dt) as data you are passing is of char * type and also strcmp() needs const char * as input arguments.

Comment: hi, this bug got sorted now I am facing another problem that the loop doesnt end? ANy suggestions

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :**

`if(strcmp(st->data,dt) == NULL)`, here `dt` is a variable of type `int`eger...

`strcmp()` needs `const char *` as i/p arguments. check the man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

**solution :**

In your code, you're calling `find()` as

```
find(start,newnode->data)
```

`newnode->data` is of type `char`, so, it's the problem with your function signature for `find()`. Change your `find()` function to

```
list *find(list *st, const char * dt)
```